# NHibernate and MVC instance vars

Tags: model-view-controller, nhibernate

I am learning NHibernate/MVC and creating a sample app that let the user store a list of book they own.  The problem i am having is that my repositories required that current login user but I dont what is the best of keeping the user details in MVC Session.  I am using forms authentication.

**login page**

```
var user = userRepository.login(username,password);

Session["user"] = user;
```

**list page**

```
var user = Session["user"] as user;

var books = bookRepository.getByGenre("Fiction",user);
```

Is this the recommend way of passing instance variables between each http request?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

The Steve Sanderson MVC book states

> In ASP.NET MVC the best kind of action method is a pure function of
>   its parameters. By this I mean that the action method reads data only
>   from its parameters and writes data only to its parameters and does
>   not refer to HttpContext or Session or any other state external to the
>   controller.

I believe the recommended way is to use a custom model binder that supplies your user id from a backing store. The model binder allows you to create a controller that doesn't care where the data comes from.

A good place to start is this post

[modelbinder-for-an-object-stored-in-session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1333573/extending-sandersons-custom-mvc-modelbinder-for-an-object-stored-in-session)

Comment: So every action in mvc will have another parameter that is the current user?  Wouldn't it easier to have a global property that the control can access the user object?

Comment: Easier yes, recommended no. I believe the idea behind extracting the session data out of the controllers is to allow for scalability and removes any assumptions that the controllers would need to make on having a global variable set. It also avoids the need to mock the http session in any unit tests.